# Archipack in Blender3.0

Tags: archipack-add-on

B"H  Archipack worked in Blender2.93  After upgrading to 3.0, archipack is no longer in Preferences.  How to reinstall?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was wondering the same thing (11 months later). Archipack was removed from Blender 3.x releases. You can download the original free version that shipped with blender, aka the 'community edition' for a donation or the full (paid) version.

All details are here: https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/wiki